# Python JSON get request for multiple websites

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

I'm trying to make a json get request on multiple urls. 
(I'm new to programming as you will see below.)

**My goal** is to run this python script with multiple links. The only thing needs to be changed is the "b" part of the link, so it can run multiple searches with different numbers (strings), preferably using a list of numbers and exporting all the results to a csv list.

**My question** is: How should I change the code so I can use a list of numbers for "b" and get all the requests? (like a loop)

Please find below my code and thank you for your time.

```
import requests
import json

a = 'https://www.g2a.com/lucene/search/filter?jsoncallback=jQuery111002521088376353553_1491736907010&skip=28837%2C28838%2C28847%2C28849%2C28852%2C28856%2C28857%2C28858%2C28859%2C28860%2C28861%2C28862%2C28863%2C28867%2C28868%2C28869%2C29472%2C29473%2C29474%2C29475%2C29476%2C29482%2C29486%2C33104&minPrice=0.00&maxPrice=640.00&cn=&kr=&stock=all&event=&platform=0&search=&genre=0&cat=0&sortOrder=popularity+desc&start=0&rows=12&steam_app_id='
b = '515220' 
c = '&steam_category=&steam_prod_type=&includeOutOfStock=false&includeFreeGames=false&_=1491736907012'
d = a + b + c

r = requests.get(d)
json_object = json.loads('{"data":%s}}' % (response.content.decode("utf-8").replace("jQuery111002521088376353553_1491736907010(", "")[:-2].replace("\'", "")))
for game in json_object["data"]["docs"]:
print ("Name: %s (Price: %s)" % (game["name"], game["minPrice"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the list of b values like below,

l = [1,2,3,4]

```
for b in l:
    d = a + b + c
    r = requests.get(d)
    json_object = json.loads('{"data":%s}}' % (response.content.decode("utf-8").replace("jQuery111002521088376353553_1491736907010(", "")[:-2].replace("\'", "")))
    for game in json_object["data"]["docs"]:
    print ("Name: %s (Price: %s)" % (game["name"], game["minPrice"]))
```